# online/offline event in phonegap version 3.6.3 is not working

Tags: events, cordova

this is my code. even after i add

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
```

plugin in my config.xml it's not detecting connection type.

html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Connection</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="connection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">Conn</div>

<div class="panel">
 <img id="imgConnection" width="240" height="240"/>

 <button id="btnCheck">Check Conn</button>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

connection.js

```
 $(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
        connection();
        $('#btnCheck').bind('touchstart',connection);
    });

function connection(){
    switch(navigator.network.connection.type)
    {
        case Connection.UNKNOWN:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', 'unknown.png');
            break;
        case Connection.ETHERNET:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', 'ethernet.png');
            break;
        case Connection.WIFI:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', 'wireless.png');
            break;
        case Connection.CELL_2G:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', '2g.png');
            break;
        case Connection.CELL_3G:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', '3g.png');
            break;
        case Connection.CELL_4G:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', '4g.png');
            break;
        case Connection.NONE:
            $('#imgConnection').attr('src', 'home.png');
            break;
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated.. how to make this thing to work. im using phonegap version 3.6.3.

im being stuck at this problem for days. i even watched many tutorials on how to make this things to work. but, i still cant get it to work. so,im asking for help. thanks